# Python Pandas - Iterate over unique columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to iterate over a list of unique column-values to create three different keys with dictionaries inside a dictionary. This is the code I have now:

```
import pandas as pd

dataDict = {}
metrics = frontendFrame['METRIC'].unique()

for metric in metrics:
    dataDict[metric] = frontendFrame[frontendFrame['METRIC'] == metric].to_dict('records')

print(dataDict)
```

This works fine for low amounts of data, but as fast as the amount of data increases this can take almost one second (!!!!).

I've tried with groupby in pandas which is even slower, and also with map, but I don't want to return things to a list. How can I iterate over this and create what I want in a faster way? I am using Python 3.6

UPDATE:

Input:

```
    DATETIME             METRIC  ANOMALY           VALUE
0   2018-02-27 17:30:32  SCORE      2.0                    -1.0
1   2018-02-27 17:30:32  VALUE      NaN                     0.0
2   2018-02-27 17:30:32  INDEX      NaN  6.6613381477499995E-16
3   2018-02-27 17:31:30  SCORE      2.0                    -1.0
4   2018-02-27 17:31:30  VALUE      NaN                     0.0
5   2018-02-27 17:31:30  INDEX      NaN  6.6613381477499995E-16
6   2018-02-27 17:32:30  SCORE      2.0                    -1.0
7   2018-02-27 17:32:30  VALUE      NaN                     0.0
8   2018-02-27 17:32:30  INDEX      NaN  6.6613381477499995E-16
```

Output:

```
{
  "INDEX": [
{
  "DATETIME": 1519759710000,
  "METRIC": "INDEX",
  "ANOMALY": null,
  "VALUE": "6.6613381477499995E-16"
},
{
  "DATETIME": 1519759770000,
  "METRIC": "INDEX",
  "ANOMALY": null,
  "VALUE": "6.6613381477499995E-16"
}],
  "SCORE": [
{
  "DATETIME": 1519759710000,
  "METRIC": "SCORE",
  "ANOMALY": 2,
  "VALUE": "-1.0"
},
{
  "DATETIME": 1519759770000,
  "METRIC": "SCORE",
  "ANOMALY": 2,
  "VALUE": "-1.0"
}],
  "VALUE": [
{
  "DATETIME": 1519759710000,
  "METRIC": "VALUE",
  "ANOMALY": null,
  "VALUE": "0.0"
},
{
  "DATETIME": 1519759770000,
  "METRIC": "VALUE",
  "ANOMALY": null,
  "VALUE": "0.0"
}]
}
```

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of your input and expected output?>

Comment: So, I updated it now. Check it out @VivekKalyanarangan

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
a = defaultdict( list )
_ = {x['METRIC']: a[x['METRIC']].append(x) for x in frontendFrame.to_dict('records')}
a = dict(a)
```

---

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = defaultdict( list )
for x in frontendFrame.to_dict('records'):
    a[x['METRIC']].append(x)
a = dict(a)
```

---

Slow:

```
dataDict = frontendFrame.groupby('METRIC').apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records')).to_dict()
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried to timeit it was actually slower @jezrael

Comment: @danielo - Can you check alternative solution?